# C# HttpClient Uri value

Tags: c#, linq, http, azure, windows-phone-8.1

I'm working on creating a WindowsPhone 8.1 app, and I'm having trouble getting the client to access the database.  I created a server-side project that works fine using web api.  I'm able to run debugger and add "/api/entityName" to return a list of all the rows in that table or just a single row if I specify an id value.  After doing a lot of testing on the client side, I think I've pinpointed my error: the uri value.  Can someone tell me what value I should be passing into the uri constructor?  Here's the method that I'm using in the client:

```
public async void GetBars()
    {
        var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:20672/tables/bars"); //seems like this value is the problem
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        barsListBox.Items.Add("right before try starts");
        // Always catch network exceptions for async methods
        try
        {
            barsListBox.Items.Add("try started");
            var result = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri); //never gets past this line. goes straight to finally
            barsListBox.Items.Add("right before linq");
            var queryAllBars =
                from bar in result
                select bar;
            barsListBox.Items.Add("linq finished");
            foreach (var bar in queryAllBars)
            {
                barsListBox.Items.Add(bar);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // Details in ex.Message and ex.HResult.       
        }
        finally
        {
            barsListBox.Items.Add("finally executed");
            httpClient.Dispose();
        }


    }
```

The database is a SQL Server database being hosted on Azure.  I've tried using the URL listed for the database in Azure, my current IP address, just about every combination of using/excluding the port number, etc but nothing seems to work.  I don't get any errors, but I also don't get anything displayed in the UI (except for the testing statements I've entered).  Try started gets printed, but right before linq doesn't, which is why I believe my problem is coming from the uri value being passed int GetStringAsync.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: The result is a `HttpResponseMessage`, you cannot use LINQ with this kind of object. Try inspecting the value of `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Midhun's answer and other answers I received, I was able to get the bars to print correctly.  I used Midhun's code above with the uri of my hosted database (the azurewebsites.net url) instead of my localhost database.  I also changed the IList to a String and wrote a method that picks out the values using IndexOf and Substring as follows:

```
start = bar.IndexOf("BarID", start) + 7;
int end = bar.IndexOf(",", start);
int id = Convert.ToInt32(bar.Substring(start, (end - start)));
Bars newBar = new Bars(id, name, street, city, state, phone, zip);
Bars.barsList.Add(newBar);
```

I then created a static list in my Bars model to add the newly created Bars items to.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try like this

```
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {

                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://Ipaddress/mammo/");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/controllername");

                        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        {   
                           IList<something> data = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IList<something>>();
                        }
               }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I published my services project to Azure and replaced the uri value with the azurewebsites.net url, and now I'm at least able to cycle through my entire method (all the test comments are being hit).  However, I'm still not getting any values to print.  Using the code that you provided above, I added the following foreach loop to print the data to my UI, but it never enters the loop.  Is there a different way I should be using to print the values onto my UI?  Thanks.

Comment: foreach (var bar in data)
                    {
                        barsListBox.Items.Add("foreach entered");
                        barsListBox.Items.Add(bar);
                    }